# Fetching KeyVault values through App Configuration

Tags: c#, azure, configuration, azure-keyvault, azure-app-configuration

I'd like to fetch both App Configuration and KeyVault values directly from IConfiguration. This is from a console application in .Net 7

Program.cs:

```
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureLogging(a => a.AddConsole())
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration(config => config.AddEnvironmentVariables())
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
    {
        config.ConfigureKeyVault();
    })
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        var env = context.HostingEnvironment;
        var startUp = new Startup(env);
        startUp.ConfigureServices(services);
        startUp.ConfigureConsoleMethods(services);
                
        _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(true); 
    })
    .Build();
```

Extension Method:

```
public static void ConfigureKeyVault(this IConfigurationBuilder config)
{
    var settings = config.Build();

    var appConfigConnString = settings.GetConnectionString("AppConfig");
    var keyVaultEndpoint = settings.GetValue<string>("KeyVault:Endpoint");
    var kvOptions = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = settings.GetValue<string>("KeyVault:ClientId") };

    config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
   {
        options.Connect(appConfigConnString);
        options.ConfigureKeyVault(x => x.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential(kvOptions)));
    });
}
```

With this setup, I can fetch my KeyVault keys like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IApiFactory, ApiFactory>(x =>
{
    var keyVault = x.GetRequiredService<IKeyVaultService>();
                
    return new ApiFactory(
        keyVault.GetSecret("SomeObj:ClientId"),
        keyVault.GetSecret("SomeObj:ClientSecret"));
});
```

But I would rather get my key's using IConfiguration, like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IApiFactory, ApiFactory>(x =>
{        
    return new ApiFactory(
        this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("SomeObj:ClientId"),
        this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("SomeObj:ClientSecret"));
});
```

## Question

How can I fetch my KeyVault values from IConfiguration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up a [key vault reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-key-vault-references-dotnet-core) in Azure App Configuration, the secret retrieved from the key vault should be accessible from `IConfiguration`.

- Make sure the key name (e.g. "SomeObj:ClientId") is the one that you set in Azure App Configuration instead of the secret name you set in Key Vault.
- Make sure the configuration is built before you attempt to access it.

Comment: I believe you are fully correct, but I'm having an issue getting values added into App Configuration via Azure Portal to load in my app. Programmatically added values load and reload just fine. Once I have this working, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: The above issue is because I accidentally created the configuration builder twice. I was migrating from a much older version of .Net and missed some code where the configuration builder was being called elsewhere. (silly me)